# Windows 10 setup showing blank/white screen during new installation

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installation

I wiped and reinstalled a thinkpad T480 to sell. All good until doing the new setup and I get to this:

[Screen just before Account page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6254s.jpg)

[Account page - showing a install modal, but a white box where the content should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cndy.jpg)

The 'Account' screen simply displays a white screen with no details. I've rebooted many times and gotten the same page. I've tried going into recovery mode but the 'fix my install' (not sure of wording) option says it can't do anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a possible graphics driver issue. I would suggest creating an unattend.xml with your answers in a file and running the installer with the `/unattend` flag. I would put it as an answer, but I don't know the specific steps required.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that the OS installation didn't even finish, the ISO image has some problem. The general methods online about white screen are all after successfully installing the OS. I would suggest you to redownload the ISO file and intall it without network connected.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a refurbished machine today. The Win10Pro setup got stuck (white screen) at "Service". I resolved the issue by selecting "offline install".